# How to make shadows softer as distance increases?

Tags: opengl, 3d, glsl, lwjgl, shadows

I'm trying to make shadows become more blurry as the distance between the caster and receiver, so they look a little more realistic.

What method can I use to achieve this?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for [soft shadows with contact hardening](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=soft+shadows+contact+hardening&t=h_&ia=web). Have you tried implementing any of the techniques found with those keywords? Did you get stuck anywhere in particular that we can help with?

Comment: Nope thanks! That was all I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method I was looking after is called "Soft Shadows with Contact Hardening".